# Java equivalent of C# StackTrace(false).FrameCount

Tags: java, c#

I am looking for the **Java** equivalent of the following **C#** code. Please help.

**C#**

```
if (new StackTrace(false).FrameCount > 2000)
{
    throw new Exception("Stop the formula calculation because risk of StackOverflowException");
}
```